# Parse with JSON.parse error server=>client node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I send a request from the client to the server, and I got this response:

```
{
    "m": "",
    "d": {
        "e": [
            {
                "k": "login",
                "m": "__10_10"
            }
        ]
    },
    "s": false,
    "t": "v"
}
```

But when I try to do JSON.parse on this response from client side I got:

```
Uncaught Message._fromJSONString: JSON.parse error:undefined
```

Code:

```
    try{
        console.log(json);
        return Message._fromJSONObject(JSON.parse(json));
    }catch(e){
        throw "Message._fromJSONString: JSON.parse error:" + e.message;
    }
```

I check my JSON from http://jsonlint.com/ and it's ok...
I really don't understand this issue, it's a special class who send this response, a Validator. From other requests I don't have this problem...

Do you have any idea about what's goig on? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have that `try`/`catch` wrapped around your code?  Get rid of it and allow the real exception to bubble up.

Comment: How do you think I should handle exception here? Thanks! I maybe found the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why I got no e.message... Yeah, it's easier with debug message xD

Comment: Please post the error message. If don't need any help anymore, either answer the question yourself if you think it's going to be useful for someone else, or delete the question.

Comment: @Vadorequest kindly look into the answer I have provided and let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was hidden by my try/catch. With the error debug message I could find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to your problem. It seems that for some reason it was taking it as normal JavaScript Object instead of JSON. This code works fine now.

```
var json ={
    "m": "",
    "d": {
        "e": [
            {
                "k": "login",
                "m": "__10_10"
            }
        ]
    },
    "s": "false",
    "t": "v"
};

 json =JSON.stringify(json); // this converts it into JSON parsable
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

JSfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/j39tP/

Comment: I couldn't do that in my source code, I don't think so, but I did it in console and it worked fine, that's why I didn't undersand the problem there.

Comment: Yes do that in your code and it should work fine. Also do mark it as an answer if it helped you :) I was happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an error similar to this this morning. I had to do two things to fix it:

1. For whatever reason, the error log was saying that I needed to put the json data in an array format, like this JSON.parse([jsondata]);
2. On top of my, my server side output had an error as well - so I guess double check that to make sure it's returning the correct result?

Not sure if this applies to your situation.

Hope this helps

Comment: "JSON.parse([jsondata]);" this does not work in @Vadorequest's case. But thanks for the answer. I am looking into it.

Comment: Ah bummer. Best of luck!